# Extract word and put it at the beginning of a line

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I have json like this:

```
{"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}
```

I want to extract request_id and put it at the beginning of a line. For example:

```
123456 {"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}
```

Can I do it with sed or another unix tool? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk (not a dedicated json parser):

```
s='{"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}'
awk -F '"request_id" *: *"' '{p=$0; sub(/".*$/, "", $2); print $2, p}' <<< "$s"
123456 {"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much. But I don't get how to change space in output after request_id(123456) to something else. I've tried this: print $2, "something else" p, but space still exists. Can you help?

Comment: So you don't space like this: `123456{"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}` is your expected output?

Comment: I should use tab instead of space

Comment: To use tab instead of space use: `awk -F '"request_id" *: *"' '{p=$0; sub(/".*$/, "", $2); print $2, p}' OFS='\t' <<< "$s"`

Comment: Or if you provide your expected output in your question I can probably understand it better.

Answer (score 4):

This will produce your posted desired output from your posted sample input:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*"\([^"]*\)".*\)/\2 \1/' file
123456 {"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}
```

If your actual input doesn't always follow the format you posted, update your question with more information and additional samples.

Comment: Hi Ed, Sorry would you mind elaborating on your answer? I am really struggling to work out exactly why the second capturing group is picking up the 123456

Comment: The first capturing group is the whole line, the second `\([^"]*\)` is any sequence of zero or more non-double quote characters between the second-last double quote on the line and the last double-quote on the line since the rest of the expression `.*"RE".*` explicitly requires 2 double quotes to be present and the first `.*` matches EVERYTHING (double quotes included) up to a double quote (greedy match).

Comment: Right I've got it, thanks a lot for explaining that Ed. I was thinking the first .*" was matching the first { only. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `jq`

```
echo '{"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}'|./jq ".request_id"
```

output is:

```
"123456"
```

see this page: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

update:

```
k='{"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}'
printf "%s %s\n" $(echo  $k|./jq ".request_id"|tr -d \")  $k
```

Comment: The `-r` flag to jq tells it to spit out "raw" output and should drop those quotes for you I believe.

Comment: jq is not a common tool, but +1 for using a JSON parser on JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using perl:

```
s='{"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}' 
echo $s | perl -pe 'print /(\d+)"}/ , " "'
123456 {"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}
```

Comment: I modified your solution to include a request OP made in his comments and to make it more readable. If you feel I have modified it too much, please feel free to revert it back. +1 for `perl` option though! `:)`

Comment: I've changed your modified answer just a bit, I believe now it's even more readable and looks a bit more like the original one :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple extraction:

```
awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1),$0}'
```

```
echo '{"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}' | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1),$0}'
123456 {"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}
```

Or just:

```
awk -F\" '$0=$(NF-1)OFS$0'
```

Answer (score 0):

bash:

```
json='{"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}'
{
    [[ $json =~ '"request_id":"'([^\"]+) ]] && echo -n "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} "
    echo "$json"
}
```

```
123456 {"time_stamp":1397718404043,"request_id":"123456"}
```